# Differnce between cursor and stream in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, database

We know that we can use stream or cursor to extract large data from database. I want to know which option is better and how cursor, stream works internally in node js.

Answer (score 1):

Internally, stream and cursor both is used socket connection. The main difference is, socket sent the data one by one for stream and for cursor, socket sent the data in a batch.